# Can \Ddots cooperate with adjusted column widths in nicematrix?

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I'm having problems getting `\Ddots` to work when I change the width of a column of my matrix.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{bNiceArray}{cccWc{2cm}c}
  b      & \Cdots & b      & \Cdots & b      \\
  \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
  b      & \Cdots & b      & \Cdots & b
\end{bNiceArray}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should desactivate the parallelization of the diagonal lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{bNiceArray}{cccWc{2cm}c}[parallelize-diags=false]
  b      & \Cdots & b      & \Cdots & b      \\
  \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
  b      & \Cdots & b      & \Cdots & b
\end{bNiceArray}
$

\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

If you want to keep the parallelization of the diagonal lines (if you have several `\Ddots` lines that should be parallel), you can also draw the big dotted line with the command `\line` in the `CodeAfter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bNiceArray}{cccccWc{4cm}c}[xdots/shorten=5pt]
1      & \Cdots & \Cdots & 1      & 2      & \Cdots & 2      \\
0      & \Ddots &        & \Vdots & \Vdots &        & \Vdots \\
\Vdots & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Vdots &        &        &        \\
0      & \Cdots & 0      & 1      & 2      & \Cdots & 2 
\CodeAfter \line{1-5}{4-7}
\end{bNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Also, thanks for authoring this package. It's completely changed how I teach linear algebra.